# setScalesPageToFit refresh

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to refresh my UIwebView after `[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];`

Is it possible to refresh without reloading the content from the internet which would be a waste on bandwidth.

Thanks,
Eds